# Vaadin Flow add a separator into the Tabs component

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

Is it possible to add a visual separator into the Tabs component between tabs? I tried to add Hr component into the verticals Tabs but it failed with an error that only Tab can be added to the Tabs component.

**UPDATED**

**This is what I have:**

[image]

**This is what I need:**

[image]

**The code**

```
Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
Tab jobsTab = VaadinUtils.createVerticalTab(VaadinIcon.WORKPLACE, getTranslation("jobs.catalog"), AllJobsView.class, null);
        tabs.add(jobsTab);

public static Tab createVerticalTab(VaadinIcon viewIcon, String viewName, Class<? extends Component> navigationTarget, Span counterSpan) {
        Icon icon = viewIcon.create();

        Direction currentLanguageDirection = VaadinUtils.getCurrentLanguageDirection();
        switch (currentLanguageDirection) {
            case LEFT_TO_RIGHT -> {
                icon.getStyle()
                        .set("box-sizing", "border-box")
                        .set("margin-inline-end", "var(--lumo-space-m)")
                        .set("margin-inline-start", "var(--lumo-space-xs)")
                        .set("padding", "var(--lumo-space-xs)");
            }
            case RIGHT_TO_LEFT -> {
                icon.getStyle()
                        .set("box-sizing", "border-box")
                        .set("margin-inline-end", "var(--lumo-space-xs)")
                        .set("margin-inline-start", "var(--lumo-space-m)")
                        .set("padding", "var(--lumo-space-xs)");
            }
        }

        RouterLink link = new RouterLink();
        link.add(icon, new Span(viewName));
        if (counterSpan != null) {
            link.add(counterSpan);
        }
        link.setRoute(navigationTarget);
        link.setTabIndex(-1);

        return new Tab(link);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As you see, it is intentionally disabled. I would recommend to study if you can achieve suitable visuals with CSS.

The `vaadin-tab` elements are in light DOM of the `vaadin-tabs`. So it allows to do several things.

E.g. if you want to be the last tab separated, you can set `margin-left: auto` to the last child, which does this:

[image]

Furthermore if I add `border-right: 1px solid var(--lumo-contrast-20pct);` to second child and `border-left: 1px solid var(--lumo-contrast-20pct);` to last one, I get.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I struggle with this a few hours and still unable to achieve what I need. I added the screenshot. I need to make this separator like two another (at the top and bottom) but unable to properly setup the margins..

Comment: Could you please show how to do the tab separation( like in your example #2) but for vertical tabs?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the experimental `Nav` component instead of `Tabs`, which is not really ideal for an app's main navigation anyway.

You'll find the `Nav` component in an application generated with https://start.vaadin.com.

Comment: Thanks. I investigated the component. Looks like it is also only working with a specific type - AppNavItem(like Tabs with Tab). Also, how to programmatically select the concrete AppNavItem in AppNav component?

Answer (score 1):

I've not worked with the Tabs or Nav components before, so I might be talking out of turn, but you might be able to achieve what you want with CSS, if you can identify the menu items as you add them and add classes to the ones you want space around.  It's a big 'if', I know, but there's no code here, so I don't know if this is feasible or not. In any case, if you can do that, then you can simply set bottom and top margins of the items around the horizontal separator and thus move them apart. Seems to me, anyway.

Well, I was thinking something like this:

```
String viewName = "Administration";
Span testSpan = new Span();
if(viewName == "Administration") {
    testSpan.addClassName("over-separator");
} else if (viewName == "Privacy Policy") {
    testSpan.addClassName("under-separator");
}
```

Then, in your CSS, set bottom and top margins in such a way as to give you the space you need.

Comment: Thanks. I added the code to the question